# Duplicating, multiplying and saving a H.264 movie file efficiently

Tags: h.264, movie, video-editing

I tried to look for free H.264 editors that could do such forementioned tasks, but i couldn't find any suitable results (probably due to my incorrect(?) search terms).

Basically, i have quite a few 20 to 40 second looping movie files (rendered with Adobe Premiere), and i would like to multiply an individual movie to about ten or twenty fold, and then save it again, preferably without the need to re-render (or re-encode?). Is this possible?

Hopefully i managed to make myself understood, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After a whole bunch of searching and testing, i ended up with Avidemux and it did the task perfectly, this time around. I'm sure there would've been a way to automatize the appending / "multiplying" of the file, but with a tablet pen (main click set as double click) and specific folder it truly went by like a breeze.

I was also interested of Smart Cutter (i quite enjoyed the interface after getting used to it), but since it was trialware the choice was clear. Still, if i would have to do these kind of tasks more often, i *might* consider purchasing it.